# Algebra prerequisites for Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

Is the chapter on groups in Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* enough to get started? What bare minimum Algebra should I be comfortable with, before studying Algebraic Topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, when covering things like the characterization of the fundamental groups of compact surfaces a couple of facts about free groups are used, also when calculating the abelianizations of the aforementioned groups.

However, I recommend that you learn these as they appear while you are reading Hatcher. I think that Hatcher's book is going to require a lot of work regardless of whether you know a lot of group theory or not. But it is a great book, and I think that learning the group theory stuff as you advance through the book is a good method.

---

As to what the "bare minimum" is: I thing that chapter on Herstein is more than enough.